# Magento 2 not sending forgot password emails, All other emails are fine

Tags: forgot-password, magento-2.3

I am using magento 2.3.5 on Ubuntu 18. Installed postfix and its already working for other order emails. Only the forgot password emails are not getting sent.

I already have installed Mageplaza SMTP and Postfix.

When customer hits submit he only sees message as "If there is an account associated with mail@mail.com you will receive an email with a link to reset your password."  But there is no email received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this. In case someone needs answer. SO this was an issue with the custom theme template. When I revert it to the default theme then it started working. Then I re-code the custom theme template and it started working.